# Can bitcoin transaction be signed offline without access to blockchain

Tags: wallet, security

To make an offline transaction signing we do the following:

[Online PC]:  Create unsigned transaction
[Offline PC]: Select and sign the transaction
[Online PC]:  Broadcast to network

Is it possible to do the following:

[offline PC]:  Create transaction
[Offline PC]: Select and sign the transaction
[Online PC]:  Broadcast to network

Answer (score 3):

If you know the unspent outputs you have the keys for, yes.

Which in practice means that you need to have seen the transactions that have paid you. Once you know that, the actual transaction to spend it can be created offline.

Comment: thanks, can the transaction history be updated on offline device after every signed transaction?

Comment: okay, incoming transactions cannot be added.

Comment: see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-to-safely-spend-from-a-compressed-key-offline/17975#17975